# Can 'The Cleansing' bounty be done everyday?

Tags: destiny

This is the bounty that gives 3 motes of light for killing 10 Majors or Ultras in a Nightfall activity.

I know you can only get rewards from the first run through each week of the Nightfall but can this bounty reward be attained by re-playing the Nightfall?

Does it appear more than once a week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Status of your nightfall completion does not matter for that bounty. So you can do that bounty on your second run, or by just redoing first part of the strike or however you like.
Just start nightfall and get to killing some majors, that's all.

As for the frequency of that bounty... Personally, I don't remember any week when we had two of those, but I could miss some. As for the future, Bungie controls the algorithm of bounty generation, and as far as I know they didn't disclose any information about it.

Comment: I believe the bounty is available all week and can only be done once a week.

Comment: Bounties are also Bungies way of Dailies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you get that bounty everyday until you complete the night fall